# mysql implement query based on multiple parameters

Tags: mysql

Hello I am implementing a filter functionality in my code. So here's the scenario.

Lets say user selects four parameters and he wants result based on what user has selected or typed on those four parameters so I will do this

```
select * from table where field1 = "f1" and field = "f2" and field3 = "field3" and field4 = "field4"
```

Problem is what if I receive two parameters then what should I do ?

One solution is I write multiple queries and based on what user has selected run that query.

But is there any other way possible in mysql to tackle this issue ? I mean is there anything like this

```
select * from table where field1 = "f1" and field = "f2" and field3 = "null" and field4 = "null"
```

but this null doesn't effect the whole query and always return true

Comment: What "code" are you using? I'm guessing it's not pure SQL here.

Comment: @xander I am using PHP

Comment: OH I see your php tag got removed! :D Well you could use a dynamic query string and use a query builder or something like that, there are many ways, also depending on how you store the filter in PHP.

Comment: @xander so mysql doesn't provide any solution to this kind a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to include a null/empty check in each one.  (Whether you use null or empty string often depends on how you're passing the values to SQL.)

Let's use one parameter as an example:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField = ? OR ? IS NULL
```

If, from your code (PHP?), you assign the same value to both of those query parameters then the logic here would only filter on `SomeField` if that value is not null.  If it is null, the `? IS NULL` check would match every record.

Simply enclose the clauses in parentheses to append more:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE
  (SomeField = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
  (AnotherField = ? OR ? IS NULL)
```

And so on, for as many optional filters as you like.  That way you just have one query and each "filter" is optional.  Passing a filter value will filter on that field, passing a null value will ignore that filter.

Comment: This is a working approach, but I still prefer to optimize the query with PHP instead, if you have access to all the data that is needed to do that. Depending on the size of the database table this might get slow if the DB engine can't chose a proper index. I'm not sure if the DB engine can optimize `NULL` columns out before executing the query internally?

Comment: @xander: Have you measured the performance?  "optimize" doesn't always mean what people assume it means.  Relational databases tend to be *very good* at optimizing query execution paths, especially if the same query is used multiple times with only changing the parameters.  Even more so if that query is made into a stored procedure.  Sending "smaller" queries that are dynamically built from code and always different removes the database's ability to cache the execution plan.

Comment: you might be right and I didn't benchmark it, but it might still be worth considering by the OP to test different ways to execute the query and compare the results.